# Sending a menu item selection to a custom view's onTouch method

Tags: android

I'm writing a custom view to be able to draw on a bitmap and I'd like to be able to pass a menu selection from my activity to have the onTouch do different things. For instance, if you select circle from the menu then the onTouch will draw a circle, if rectangle, a rectangle etc.  Am I going about this the right way? Is there a way to pass the menu item selection to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a getter/setter to accomplish this.  Not sure if that's the best way but it works.